# rmdir() Not Deleting an Empty Folder - PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently building a very low level CMS for friend's artist web page that will allow her to upload, edit, and delete images along with designating categories for them and posting news posts about shows and so on.

I'm sure there is a very easy solution to this problem of mine but my inexperience in programming has me left at a loss; so here goes.

**The Problem**

The problem occurs on a page where the user can delete an image that has been uploaded. Here is the snippet of code where the problem occurs:

```
    // Assign selection to variables in memory...
    $img_id = $data["img_name"];

    // First, collect the file path to the image being deleted...
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT img_path FROM img_uploads WHERE img_id = '$img_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    list($img_path) = mysql_fetch_row($rs);

    // Then delete that row from the DB...
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM img_uploads WHERE img_id = '$img_id'") or die(mysql_error());

    // Now, using the file path collected earlier, delete that file from the server.
    unlink($img_path);

    // Quickly make sure that the file has been deleted by checking if it exists... if it still exists return error.
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        $err[] = "ERROR - There was an error deleting the file! Please try again.";
        $_SESSION["errors"] = $err;
        header("Location: img_del.php?doDel=failed");
        exit();
    }

    // Scan the directory now that a file has been deleted to see if the dir is empty. If so, delete it. (No use in having empty folders!)
    $file_types = array("gif","jpg","png"); // file types to scan for...
    $path_parts = pathinfo($img_path); // get the directory from the file path...
    $dir = $path_parts["dirname"] . "/"; // assign it to a new variable...
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    $scan = scandir($dir); // now, scan that directory...
    $image_found = FALSE;
    for($i=0; $i<count($scan); $i++) { 
        if ($scan[$i] != '.' && $scan[$i] != '..' && in_array(end(explode('.', $scan[$i])), $file_types)) { 
            $image_found = TRUE;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    if(!$image_found) {
        rmdir($dir);
    }
```

I first delete the DB row containing image info, then delete the file from the server. *this works fine*, however, I also want to check if the directory is left empty after deleting that file. I check if the directory is empty using a loop and if no file is found, I run `mkdir()`. **For some reason it keeps returning an error saying that the directory is not empty**

I've searched the web and this site for a solution but I've yet to find one. I'm sure it's out there but I'm having trouble finding it which why I came here. What should I do?

Thanks in advance for any help submitted!

**NOTE**
I have also checked for hidden files and folders but no luck...

[Here is a link to an image that pretty much sums up my problem in a nutshell](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/4848/unled1goy.png)

Comment: You trust Explorer to tell you when a directory is empty?

Comment: lol not exactly but i've checked for hidden files and such but no luck :/

Comment: make sure you have privilege over that directory
chown and chmod :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure PHP has permission to delete the file? Since you say you've checked for hidden files, this seems to be the only remaining option. CHMOD 0777 when in doubt (I'd never recommend this usually, but if you're deleting it anyway...), and make sure the folder has the proper owner to let php delete it.

Comment: when i originally create the folder during the upload process, i set permissions to 0700 -- could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @lemonpole: Try changing the permissions, I am pretty sure PHP cannot access it then.

Comment: I changed chmod to 0777 `chmod($dir, 0777);` as such and now the error has changed to a permissions one. So should I make permissions during upload, set to 0777 or is there a security concern when doing that?

Comment: Do not set them to 0777 upon upload. But make sure PHP has permission to delete the folder when it's done...

Comment: I've also set `chown($dir, $_SESSION["user_id"]);` to give permission to the admin user and the error has returned saying that the directory is not empty. That must be the problem. I've used the `/dir ah` command line and it returns one file: `thumbs.db` -- is this what is preventing the del?

Comment: Delete thumbs.db and you'll be able to delete the folder.