# Delete folder and all inside contents function returns "directory not empty"

Tags: php, rmdir

Below is my attempt to delete a folder and all its content. A folder may contain zip files and folders with files.

```
public function deleteFolder($dir){
    if(file_exists($dir)){
        $it = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($it,
                         \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
        foreach($files as $file) {
            if ($file->isDir()){
                rmdir($file->getRealPath());
            } else {
                unlink($file->getRealPath());
            }
        }
        rmdir($dir);
    }           
}
```

but it returns the following error:

> rmdir(C:\Juliver\UIUX\pd-loader\loader/temp/utso-pulgada-pd-loader-5066a7e0298a):
>
> Directory not empty in C:\Juliver\UIUX\pd-loader\loader\Patcher.php on line 95

`line 95` points to `rmdir($dir);` line

If I check the folder **utso-pulgada-pd-loader-5066a7e0298a**, I see that it's already empty but it throws me the above error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rmdir() Not Deleting an Empty Folder - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642655/rmdir-not-deleting-an-empty-folder-php)

Comment: Or you could just execute a command, e.g. `rm -rf examplefolder` for *nix or `del /F/Q/S*.* > NULL` followed by `rmdir /Q/S examplefolder` for windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recursively delete a directory and its entire contents (files + sub dirs) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dirname = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test';
array_map('unlink', glob("$dirname/*.*"));
rmdir($dirname);
```

try this, this remove all the file present in the folder, and that folder too

Answer (score 0):

Directory may contain other directories so you have to use a recursive function.

```
function removeDir($path) {
    $files = glob("$path/*");
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            removeDir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    rmdir($path);
}
```

Now is enough to call removeDir("/my/nice/path");
If you see the directory already empty, try to check for hidden files and be sure that you have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have already checked its not a file permissions issue. As your code works for me but not you, it makes me wonder if it is a to do with PHP file stat or Real Path caching.

Unlinking a file should clear stat cache for individual file automatically. However PHP bugs have [previously been known to cause this issue with rmdir](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54987).

Try doing a [clearstatcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) after the rmdir statement in your foreach block.

Previously I've used glob (mentioned in other answers) so I've no idea how RecursiveDirectoryIterator works re file handles; as a long shot try destroying these objects ( `unset($files);` `unset($it)` ) before your final rmdir.